# Persist intermediate states of Spark job in Amazon S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have incremental raw data that is stored on an Amazon S3 bucket.

I would like to run a Spark job on this raw data to perform some transformations, but as it's a large volume of data, I would prefer to avoid running each time the Spark job from scratch.

Is it possible to persist the state of the Spark job, so that each time I run a new job, I only process the new data that has been added after the previous job?

Thanks a lot